# Get gradient resource from shape drawable

Tags: android, gradient, android-drawable, android-resources

I seem to be really stuck with the following problem:

I have a shape defined in an XML file, described as followed:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/star_shape_item">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#32816f6f"
                android:gradientRadius="40%p"
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:type="radial" >
            </gradient>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I am drawing this shape on a canvas multiple times.

Now, what i would like to do is to be able to dynamically change the center of the gradient in my programming code. 
I am able to get the shape from my resources with:

```js
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.star_shape);
RotateDrawable starShape = (RotateDrawable)(layers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.star_shape_item));
```

But how would i get the GradientDrawable out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found the answer in case someone else encounters a similar problem:

```js
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.star_shape);
RotateDrawable starShape = (RotateDrawable) (layers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.star_shape_item));
GradientDrawable shapeGradient = (GradientDrawable) starShape.getDrawable();
```